# Matlab: making the grid in plot logarithmic

Tags: matlab, grid, logarithm

I have plotted to vectors against each other, and they are already logarithmic and everything is fine with that. But now that I have my plot i want the grid to be logarithmic. I write "grid on" in my code, and I think there should be a way to do this in the plot, but I can't remember how. How do I make the grid logarithmic?

Answer (score 4):

If you use [`loglog`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/loglog.html), [`semilogx`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/semilogx.html) or [`semilogy`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/semilogy.html) instead of `plot`, the grid will automatically be on a log scale for the corresponding axes when using `grid on`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have already plotted the axes, you can execute the following on the command line:

```
set(gca,'yscale','log') %# to set the y-axis to logarithmic
set(gca,'xscale','log') %# to set the x-axis to logarithmic
```

Have a look at [`axes properties`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) to find out what else you can modify.